# output horizontal loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

i have code

```
even = int(input("total even number : "))
print(even, "first even number : ")
for i in range(2,even*2,2):
    print (i,end=", ")
print(even*2,end=" ")
```

and output

```
total even number : 5
5 first even number :
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

while the output I want is like this :

```
total even number : 5
5 first even number :2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid printing the trailing newline, change `print(even, "first even number : ")` to `print(even, "first even number : ", end="")`.